# Cannot cast array data from dtype('0') to dtype('int32') using scipy peak_widths method

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am trying to run the code below, but when it tries to calculate the widths of the peaks it gives me this error:

`TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'`

I have read the documentation on `scipy.signal.find_peaks` and `scipy.signal.peak_widths` but everything that I have read tells me what I have should work.

Here is the link for the .csv file I am using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18rtoGSRRLmoeOglvuAYvd2S3NeLvw90T/view?usp=sharing

```py
import pandas as pd
import scipy.signal as sp

signal_data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
signal = signal_data['Signal']
retention_time = signal_data['Retention Time (s)']

peaks = sp.find_peaks(signal, distance=300, prominence=2000)
print(peaks)

widths = sp.peak_widths(signal, peaks)
print(widths)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should be clearer about where the error is occurring.  When I try your data (thanks for the csv!) `find_peaks` works fine.  It's the `sp.peak_widths` call that raises the error.  Normally we ask for a traceback to get full error information.  @AchinthaIhalage, is on the right track - you need to use just part of the `find_peaks` output, not all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) example, output of `sp.find_peaks` is a N-dimensional array. So you need to do the following in the relevant line.

```
peaks, _ = sp.find_peaks(signal, distance=300, prominence=2000)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is going on.  I actually had to run my own test case before you explanation made sense.